# Not to escape attribute contents in lxml (python3)?

Tags: python

In this python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import lxml.etree as etree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_tree = etree.XML("""<檔>
<段 屬性="段落的意思">中文內容</段>
</檔>""")
    xsl_tree = etree.XML("""<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<節點 名稱="{local-name()}" 屬性="值"><xsl:apply-templates /></節點>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>""")
    transform = etree.XSLT(xsl_tree)
    result = transform(xml_tree)
    print(etree.tostring(xml_tree, encoding="UTF-8").decode('UTF-8'))
    print(etree.tostring(result, encoding="UTF-8").decode('UTF-8'))
```

The result I get is:

```
<檔>
<段 屬性="段落的意思">中文內容</段>
</檔>
<節點 名稱="&#x6A94;" 屬性="&#x503C;">
<節點 名稱="&#x6BB5;" 屬性="&#x503C;">中文內容</節點>
</節點>
```

It seems that the XSLT transformation escapes unicode characters (even if they are XML-safe) for attribute values. Is there a way to output the transformed XML with attribute values non-escaped? I want the result like this:

```
<檔>
<段 屬性="段落的意思">中文內容</段>
</檔>
<節點 名稱="檔" 屬性="值">
<節點 名稱="段" 屬性="值">中文內容</節點>
</節點>
```

Comment: Try using `etree.tostring(result, encoding="unicode", method="html")` (or simply `str(result)` instead). Using `unicode` as encoding is better then using `UTF-8` and then decoding.

Comment: My real case is to output a full xhtml document. The `str(result)` approach does work but has several problems: (1) It automatically adds `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` (NOT a valid xhtml) just after the `<head>` tag; (2) It outputs tags such as `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>` to `<input type="checkbox" disabled></input>`, which is ugly and invalid; (3) It doesn't output the `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` xml declaration. Is there someway to avoid them?